# Launching my app from assistant with voice action

Tags: android, search, voice, assistant

My production app is consuming the com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION.

At least until September it was possible to ask Google Assistant "Search XY in MyApp" which launched my App from Google assistant.
The intent had XY as SearchManager.QUERY.

But now this has stopped working. I didn't integrate app indexing in my app.

So my question is there any other action necessary except registering for the com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION intent to get launched from Google Assistant?

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```